# How to show required field with jqtouch in iphone view?

Tags: iphone, html, user-interface, webkit, jqtouch

I've just started designing pages particularly for iphone browser (safari).
I don't know if jqtouch is best or not, but I started working on it.

Till now I learned initialization of jqtouch, and also implemented some [touch events](http://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/callbackevents) (tap, swipe).

Now I am planning to create user interface and forms. For that I take a look on [demo](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home) (Best viewed in [webkit](http://webkit.org/)).

Now coming to my question, that what would be the best way to show required field in iphone view?

You can post any suggestions on UI creation for iphone..

Question belongs to only HTML, not related to objective c!

Comment: Interesting Date picker: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sw/

Comment: Or something like: `<input type="text" name="txtContractorSignature" placeholder="Contractor Signature (required)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, I don't think there is a convention for indicating a required form field in iPhone. So, it really is up to the developers. It also depends on how you implement the form fields. There are a few different ways you could do this. For example,

1. Text input field with a placeholder attribute
2. Drill down form, e.g. Settings
3. Key-value fields, e.g. Contacts

[image]

For the first option, you may have more space to put in more informative wording, such as that suggested by Vikas: "Username (required)".

For the latter two, you might just follow the desktop convention by adding an asterisk in the front/back of the label, e.g. "* Username".

Comment: Thanks, I had ended up by using "Username (required)". It looks like you had good experience in mobile app development, so can you suggest me out for UI creation of web pages, specially designed for safari/iPhone. Currently I'm using jqtouch and it's default css (apple/jqt that comes with the download pack) and customizing it, are there any other frameworks or plug-ins?

Comment: I didn't notice you commented on your own post :p
jQT is a nice framework, but one may find that it is still missing quite a few UI components as they delve deeper. I haven't worked with Sencha yet, but I'm looking at adopting it for my next mobile Web project. Another mobile development framework on the horizon is jQuery Mobile, which is still under development for late 2010.

Comment: I just hope that the development completes asap. http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/Mobile